# How to calculate total sales between start and end of previous month in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the total savings between start of previous month of current time (example - `1/2/2021`) and end of previous month of current time (example - `28/2/2021`). Here is my attempt below:

```
Month Saving =
    CALCULATE(
            SUMX(Savings,Savings[Forecast Annual Cost Reduction - Use USD exchange rate of the day]),
            DATESBETWEEN(LASTDATE('Dates'[Date]),STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Dates'[Date]),-1,MONTH)),ENDOFMONTH(DATEADD('Dates'[Date],-1,MONTH))
))
```

But this is giving me error and not working. Can anyone please help me on this? I want to get a single number and visualize it on Gauge or Card in canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `Savings[Forecast Annual Cost Reduction - Use USD exchange rate of the day]` is a column reference and not an attempt to subtract two different columns , try changing this:

```
DATESBETWEEN(
LASTDATE('Dates'[Date]),
STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Dates'[Date]),-1,MONTH)),
ENDOFMONTH(DATEADD('Dates'[Date],-1,MONTH))
)
```

to this:

```
DATESBETWEEN(
'Dates'[Date],//Only Dates[Date] reference
STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(LASTDATE('Dates'[Date]),-1,MONTH)),
ENDOFMONTH(DATEADD('Dates'[Date],-1,MONTH))
)
```

or this:

```
PARALLELPERIOD('Dates'[Date],-1,MONTH)
```